# Autonomy | IDOL search API

Tags: search, autonomy, hp-haven, hp-idol-ondemand

Can someone point me to a tutorial or API resource for Autonomy IDOL search?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also, the API is pretty well documented if you go to the following URL -

http://[autonomy_url]?action=help

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to an automater acount?
The knowledge base section contains some examples.
If you are using the JAVA API there are JAVADOC with some examples
The COM API contains sample code.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main sources I tend to use, for almost any IDOL Server work: the built in help, the IDOL Server Administration guide and the support site.

Experimentation can be worthwhile, once you have some familiarity with the system.